# Java gateway process exited before sending its port number error while setting pyspark master yarn_client

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

im receiving Java gateway process exited before sending its port number error when i set pyspark master equal to yarn_client while defining spark session configs. its working fine while setting master local.

im running these on jupiter notebook and the error is returned there.

my code is like below

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark_hadoop").setMaster("yarn_client").set("spark.executor.memory","5g")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

and full error is like this

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2a71daf20656> in <module>
      1 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark_hadoop").setMaster("yarn_client").set("spark.executor.memory","5g")
----> 2 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
      3 sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=create_spark_conf().setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.driver.memory","8g").set("spark.executor.memory", '8g').set('spark.executor.cores', 4))
      4 sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
      5 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    142                 " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
    143 
--> 144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
    146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    337         with SparkContext._lock:
    338             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 339                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    340                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    341 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

im using ubuntu 18. hadoop and yarn are all set up and i have tested both java 8 & 11
JAVA_HOME , YARN_CONF_DIR , HADOOP_CONF_DIR are all set in ~/.bashrc

after some modification the error changed to this:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2ee19c87679b> in <module>
      2 findspark.init()
      3 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark_hadoop").setMaster("yarn").set("spark.executor.memory","5g")
----> 4 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
      5 sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
      6 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    145         try:
    146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 147                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148         except:
    149             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    207 
    208         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    327         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    328         """
--> 329         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    330 
    331     @classmethod

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1584         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1585         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1586             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1587 
   1588         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1675283388270_0012 failed 2 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1675283388270_0012_000002 timed out. Failing the application.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

i have one master node and 2 slave nodes each on separate vm (3 vm's in total)
in master node yarn-site.xml file is like as default and i havent modified it but in slaves is have added lines below:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
```

yarn and spark both run on master vm and yarn dashboard is accessible from http://hadoop-master:8088/cluster

[this is a shot of yarn dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i86lI.png)

[description of one of the applications 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN879.png)

[description of one of the applications 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RerzJ.png)

Comment: Please edit again to include your yarn-site.xml and add more details about where YARN is running, in relation to the Spark code. A VM? What host/address? Do you need a port forward to YARN from the VM?

Comment: Click on the link of one of the application ids in YARN. Then find logs in there

Comment: the images added. in Diagnostics it seys "Application application_1675283388270_0012 failed 2 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1675283388270_0012_000002 timed out. Failing the application."

Comment: Sure, but each app attempt has its own logs, which are only shown in the YARN UI, not from Spark/jupyter client. Go to the `History Tracking URL` link. Or `Logs` links in second image

Answer (score 0):

`yarn_client` is not a valid master.

[It is only `"yarn"`. And you need a valid `yarn-site.xml` configured in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/running-on-yarn.html).

To deploy as a "client", you'd use something like `spark-submit --deploy-mode=client app.py`.

Also, for local testing, I'd suggest not using a whole 5g (or 8g? Why are you setting the config twice and overriding the master?) of memory.

Comment: when i set master to "yarn" i receive same error.

i have configured   yarn-site.xml like what this link explained 
[link](https://medium.com/@jootorres_11979/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-3-2-1-multi-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-nodes-567ca44a3b12)

how can i set the deploy mode in code? i dont work with spark shell

and the third line of the code was for test and must be deleted

Comment: Those steps have very specific IP addresses and hostnames, so without knowing exact steps you took on your own network, hard to say what the issue is. From Jupyter, or any Python IDE, client mode is the default, but you can use [`spark.submit.deployMode=client`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties) in the config. though, I suggest you try using `pyspark` REPL before using Jupyter

Comment: You could also follow [my example using Docker](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/hdfs-reader.ipynb) instead of doing everything in Virtualbox

Comment: Error simply says it timed out connecting to yarn. Please delete comments and edit your question to include logs